# Is there an easy way to convert ESC/P spool files to an image format on command line?

Tags: conversion, file-conversion

I am currently trying to convert ESC/P spool files from an old machine, which only has a parallel printer port, to an image format (I don't really care which).

At the moment all I have found are closed source commercial programs or not really functioning scripts, I can't get to run.

Are there any (easy) command line tools I can use to perform this task?